# What's the difference between the french and the german double bass bow?

Tags: bow, double-bass

There are two kind of bows for double bass:

[image]

(*French on top, German bottom*)

The [related wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bass#Bows) mentions some technique differences, but doesn't specify if the outcome is different or not.

Is there any difference in the sound outcome that these two different bows produce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They shouldn't sound any different.  They're gripped differently, which causes there to be certain tendencies, but the goal is for them to sound the same.  Any skilled player should be able to play both and make them sound indistinguishable.

Comment: I agree- I can tell you that for me German is much more comfortable, but I never noticed a difference in sound.